# Transforming SQL query to mongo using aggregate framework

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have below data in my mongo collection.

```
db.tempTest.insert([{
  "id"   : "12345",
  createdOn : ISODate("2016-09-15T19:25:00.000Z"),
  "addr" : "address1",
  "book" : "book1"
}, {
  "id"   : "12345",
  createdOn : ISODate("2016-09-14T19:25:00.000Z"),
  "addr" : "address2",
  "book" : "book2"
}, {
  "id"   : "12346",
  createdOn : ISODate("2016-09-15T19:26:00.000Z"),
  "addr" : "address3",
  "book" : "book3"
}, {
  "id"   : "12346",
  createdOn : ISODate("2016-09-15T19:26:01.000Z"),
  "addr" : "address4",
  "book" : "book4"
}, {
  "id"   : "12346",
  createdOn : ISODate("2016-09-14T19:26:01.000Z"),
  "addr" : "address5",
  "book" : "book5"
}, {
  "id"   : "12347",
  createdOn : ISODate("2016-09-14T19:26:01.000Z"),
  "addr" : "address6",
  "book" : "book6"
}, {
  "id"   : "12347",
  createdOn : ISODate("2016-09-10T19:26:01.000Z"),
  "addr" : "address7",
  "book" : "book7"
}, {
  "id"   : "12345",
  createdOn : ISODate("2016-09-14T19:25:00.000Z"),
  "addr" : "address8",
  "book" : "book8"
}]);
```

Query corresponding to SQL in Postgres would be as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idnew ORDER BY createdOn ASC) AS rownumber,
         * 
     FROM temp) AS TEMP 
WHERE 
    rownumber = 1 
    AND idnew IN ('12345', '12346', '12347') 
ORDER BY 
    createdOn ASC
```

I am new to mongo db. I went through aggregation framework and was able to use $match but am not able to fetch the document with least createdOn from the idnew group using $group. I need all the fields of the documents satisfying the conditions.
Please help to frame the query for mongo shell.

**Resultset should be as below**:

```
{
  "id"   : "12347",
  createdOn : ISODate("2016-09-10T19:26:01.000Z"),
  "addr" : "address7",
  "book" : "book7"
}, {
  "id"   : "12345",
  createdOn : ISODate("2016-09-14T19:25:00.000Z"),
  "addr" : "address8",
  "book" : "book8"
},  {
  "id"   : "12346",
  createdOn : ISODate("2016-09-14T19:26:01.000Z"),
  "addr" : "address5",
  "book" : "book5"
}
```

With lot of searches and trials, I could manage to extract data 
but format gets changed when $arrayElemAt function is used. Sharing 
query below.
Please help me in converting this output to the one shared above.

```
db.tempTest.aggregate(
   [

     {$sort : {createdOn:1}},
     { $group : { _id : "$id", details: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
     {$project:
      {

          details: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$details", 0 ] }

      }
  }

   ]
)
```

As of now, output shows as :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "12347",
    "details" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57dc1b094c105db1a666b0a8"),
        "id" : "12347",
        "createdOn" : ISODate("2016-09-10T19:26:01.000Z"),
        "addr" : "address7",
        "book" : "book7"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "12345",
    "details" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57dc1b094c105db1a666b0a3"),
        "id" : "12345",
        "createdOn" : ISODate("2016-09-14T19:25:00.000Z"),
        "addr" : "address2",
        "book" : "book2"
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "12346",
    "details" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57dc1b094c105db1a666b0a6"),
        "id" : "12346",
        "createdOn" : ISODate("2016-09-14T19:26:01.000Z"),
        "addr" : "address5",
        "book" : "book5"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
db.tempTest.aggregate(
   [
     
     {$sort : {createdOn:1}},
     { $group : { _id : "$id", id : { $first: '$id' }, createdOn : { $first: '$createdOn' }, 
       addr : { $first: '$addr' },book : { $first: '$book' } } 
     },
     {$sort : {createdOn:1}}
   ]
)
```